# Is there a difference in decryption of a message if more than two primes are given?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So, I've been looking at RSA Encryption, and I came across Multiple-prime RSA. Is there a different way to go about decryption of a given message if there are more than two primes mentioned? Or does the procedure stay the same, regardless of how many primes you use?

Comment: There is no explicit occurrence of primes in the decryption $m = c^d \bmod n$. Or do you mean CRT-RSA?

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for CRT-RSA. So I suppose there is no difference, thanks!